# Translation of "(Completely) up to you"

Tags: phrase

How would you say "Completely up to you"?

> A: Where should we go today?
>
> B: Completely up to you.

I can think of "Komplett wie du willst" or "Komplett wie du möchtest".

> A: Wohin sollen wir heute gehen?
>
> B: Komplett wie du willst/möchstest.

Is that correct, and are there other ways to say it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your translated answer is not completely correct.

When you say

> Completely up to you.

you are basically passing the decision back to the asking person. Even though you have been asked something, you let another one decide.

So in german you would for example go with

> Deine Entscheidung! (You decide!)
>   Es ist voll und ganz (completely) deine Entscheidung.

Or

> Die Entscheidung überlasse ich dir. (I pass that decision to you.)

Even though there is the word "komplett" in german, as a native speaker I would not consider this to be the right choice in this case.

Comment: Common sentence in this case would also be "Ganz Deine Entscheidung"

Comment: Just a note: Generally I prefer „vollständig“ over „komplett“. Here however, as you write „ganz“ fits well. „(das ist) ganz Dir überlassen“ or „ganz wie Du möchtest“ are variants of what you propose.

Comment: Kann man " Ich überlasse es dir" auch in diesem Zusammenhang sagen?

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Ja. Besser: "Das überlasse ich dir."

Answer (score 1):

Often heard:

> "Wo wollen wir hin[gehen]?" - "Sag du [es mir]!"

Comment: By far the most common one amongst friends and colleagues

Comment: Ist das regional? Das habe ich noch nie gehört. Klingt fast wie eine direkte Übersetzung aus dem Englischen.

Answer (score 1):

Das bleibt ganz allein dir überlassen.